# jQuery $.get or $.post to catch page load error (eg. 404)

Tags: jquery, post, get

How do you catch Server Error or 404 page not found, when you use $.get or $.post ?

For example:

```
$.post("/myhandler", { value: 1 }, function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

That will do absolutely nothing if there is a Server Error loading "/myhandler", or if it is not found.

How do you make it notify you if there is an error?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use `error` handler on [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/myhandler", 
    data: {value: 1},
    type: 'post',
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('status:' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
    },
    success: function(data){}
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/RafuW/)

Comment: So is this not possible with $.get?

Comment: @Reigel Beautiful!  Didn't realize the load callback has a Status parameter.

Answer (score 59):

you could do

```
$.post("/myhandler", { value: 1 }, function(data) {
  alert(data);
}).fail(function(){ 
  // Handle error here
});
```

fail will be called if theres an error

Comment: +1 for fail function. it does the job!
You can use it like this: 
.fail(function(e){
 if(e.status == 404){
// ...
 }
 else{
// ...
 }
});

Comment: Older code with .error() wasn't catching anything. Simply switching it to fail() did the trick.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it directly answers the question, rather than asking everyone to use a different function.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are nice and all, but there's alternative solutions, namely [`.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), [`.ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError) and other Ajax event handlers (check the ajaxSetup doc page for more info on the rest).

For example, with `.ajaxError` you can setup a global handler of all your ajax errors from `.post`, `.get`, `.getJSON` and `.ajax` for a specific set of elements.

```
$(selector).ajaxError(function(event, xhr, ajaxOptions, errorThrown) {
    // handle ajax error here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.ajax` instead and use the `error` callback.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) , [`stausCode`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings) option

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   statusCode : {
     // called on `$.get()` , `$.post()`, `$.ajax()`
     // when response status code is `404`
     404 : function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
           }
     }
 });

// $.get("/path/to/url/");
// $.post("/path/to/url/");
// $.ajax({url:"/path/to/url/"})
```