# jquery $.ajax not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have following bit of code which I am tring to run

```
   $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: './animationPlay.php',
      data: 'animation='+text,
      type: 'POST',
      datatype: 'text',
      success: function(data) { alert("succsess") },
      error: function(ts) { alert('error:'+ts.responseText) }
   });
```

I have seen [how to catch ajax query post error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833951/how-to-catch-ajax-query-post-error) and [jQuery $.get or $.post to catch page load error (eg. 404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687235/jquery-get-or-post-to-catch-page-load-error-eg-404) but it doesn't work for my code.It is simply set to "error". How do I get more detail about what's gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I tried

```
error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
  console.log(xhr.statusText);
  console.log(textStatus);
  console.log(error);
}
```

I got error, error, an empty string in console. What does it mean?

Comment: display nothing blank alert

Comment: @Baadshah - he shows in his code that he is trying to capture the error, but that `ts.responseText` returns nothing

Comment: Try removing the `.` from the url. so it is `url: '/animationPlay.php'`

Comment: `datatype` vs `dataType`?

Comment: @Jack I think jQuery should handle that nicely and just ignore it, using the default for `dataType` (so best guess, unless there's a globally set default elsewhere in the script).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist What jQuery should do and actually does ... not always the same thing, so it's best to err on the safe side :)

Comment: @Tim B James: it doesn't make any difference

Comment: what browser are you using for debugging?

Comment: @wirey: I tried in firefox n chrome

Comment: Open up your debugger.. check network tab to see if it's hitting your page successfully..  Check response from your page in network tab.. if it is hitting your page and sending a response then it's something on the server side that you need to debug.

Comment: @user2156244 were you able to figure out how to use the network tab? if not I can give you an example

Comment: @wirey: yes please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: './animationPlay.php',
        data: {
            animation: text
        },
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'text',
        success: function(data) { alert("succsess") },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('status:' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
        }
```

Comment: this may help with your 0 status code issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0

Answer (score -1):

Try sending the post data as an object...

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: './animationPlay.php',
    data: {
        animation: text
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) { alert("succsess") },
    error: function(ts) { alert('error:'+ts.responseText) }
});
```

Comment: Not going to make a difference, the object literal is going to get converted into an identical querystring anyway.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Wouldn't that not be true since this a post, not a get?

Comment: I am new in jquery. I have value text which changes on click. Is it possible to pass value of text by this way?

Comment: @user2156244 Yes, the value of `text` is passed as the parameter `animation`.

Comment: @Archer: no change, still same blank alert

Comment: @ColinDeClue The conversion from object to string seems to always happen, regardless of request type, judging from the source code. It's additionally appended to the URL for a GET request though, as stated in the docs.

Comment: Right, but this is a POST, not a GET. So, it's not a query string.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: './animationPlay.php',
      data: 'animation='+text,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(data) { alert("succsess") },
      error: function(ts) { alert('error:'+ts.responseText) }
      contentType:'SET THE CONTENT TYPE'
   });
```

Check for existense of the URL

Comment: still display nothing blank alert

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'animationPlay.php',
        data:  text,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',       //<== see, in your question's code you have small 't'
        success: function(data) { alert("succsess") },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
        }
```